# GD Transparency PNG

Tags: gd

So I basically have this:

```
$img = imagecreatefrompng('assets/other/redcircle.png');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($img);
```

So the redcircle.png file has a transparency (with anti aliasing).  But GD just turns all the transparency in black?  Is there a way to get back the original transparency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell GD to save the alpha using imagesavealpha: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php